# MVC, Azure Active Directory - Find first time user is logged in and authenticated

Tags: session, authentication, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

I have a MVC project that uses Azure Active Directory. I need to find session start where user has been authenticated. 
So far I have tried Startup.Auth.cs in:

```
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
        {

        }
```

and also Global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Does anyone know where session is started first time and user is authenticated? I tried SecurityTokenValidated but seems to be to erly in the pipeline:

[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ7G6.png)

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, it would be in the [OnTokenValidated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.ontokenvalidated?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectEvents.OnTokenValidated);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.0) event.

> Invoked when an IdToken has been validated and produced an AuthenticationTicket.

For ASP.NET non-core, I think you could use the [SecurityTokenValidated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect.openidconnectauthenticationnotifications.securitytokenvalidated(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.SecurityTokenValidated) event:

> Invoked after the security token has passed validation and a ClaimsIdentity has been generated.

Are you using ASP.NET Identity? In that case, you could use the `SignInAsync` method which is triggered on successful login.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried the SecurityTokenValidated but in this pipeline the user is still null. See original question I updated it with screenshot.